# how to redirect output to multiple log files

Tags: linux, io-redirection, tee

How to redirect standard output to multiple log files?
The following does not work:

```
some_command 1> output_log_1 output_log_2 2>&1
```

Comment: With [`zsh`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/), you can use `some_command >output_log_1 >output_log_2`.

Comment: @jofel That's incorrect, check my answer below with example from zsh manual.

Answer (score 119):

See `man tee`:

> NAME: tee  - read from standard input and write to standard output and files
>
> SYNOPSIS: tee [OPTION]... [FILE]...

Accordingly:

```
echo test | tee file1 file2 file3
```

Comment: can the stderr be also redirected in more than one file?

Comment: Yes, it can be done by virtue of redirection: 
find / -name test 2>&1 | tee file1 file2 file3

Comment: @akond, 
`cmd 2>&1 | tee log1 log2`

I tried executing like above, but i need to press ctrl-c to redirect it to second log file. also the output is printed on the console.  I want command output to be redirected to logs but not on the console. any help is appreciated.

Comment: @doubledecker The `tee` command writes `stdin` to file(s) and *also* to `stdout`. If you don't want the output to appear on the terminal, you have to redirect to `/dev/null` like you normally would.

Comment: Just a side note: `tee` has a very useful `-a` switch, which allows you to append to multiple files, just like `>>` would.

Comment: It is also possible to append to multiple files: `echo test | tee --append file1 file2`

Comment: The problem with `tee` i believe is it truncates existing output and overwrites. Is there any other solution than tee?

Comment: tee -a will append

Comment: To avoid output in `stdout` you want to use a redirect to one of your files: `... | tee file1 file2 >fil3`. Now output sent to `stdout` by `tee` gets written to `file3`

Answer (score 18):

It's an old post but I just found it now...

Instead of redirecting the output to `> /dev/null` you can redirect it to the last file:

```
echo "foobarbaz" | tee file1 > file2
```

Or for appending the output:

```
echo "foobarbaz" | tee -a file1 >> file2
```

Comment: this is more or less what other answer said (except for `-a ` in tee)

Answer (score 15):

Let's say your output is generated from a function, `cmd()` :

```
cmd() {
    echo hello world!
}
```

To redirect the output from `cmd` to two files, but not to the console, you can use:

```
cmd | tee file1 file2 >/dev/null
```

This will work for multiple files, given any data source piping to tee:

```
echo "foobarbaz" | tee file1 file2 file3 file4 > /dev/null
```

This will also work:

```
echo $(cmd) | tee file1 file2 >/dev/null
```

Without the `/dev/null` redirection, tee will send output to stdout *in addition* to the files specified.

For example, if this is run from the console, you'll see the output there.  Run from a crontab, the output will appear the status message which is mailed to you (also see Gilles' answer here https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/100833/3998).

This worked for me in bash on Ubuntu 12.04, and has been verified in Ubuntu 14.04 using GNU bash 4.3.11(1), so it should work on any recent GNU bash version.

Comment: @doubledecker -- this looks like it satisfies your conditions, so can be accepted as the answer.  Also, +1 as I've tested this under GNU bash (`version 4.3.11(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu)`) in Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 5):

@strugee's answer for zsh is not safe to use. The safe way to do this would be to enclose `some_command` in brace brackets like:

```bsh
{some_command} >output_log_1 >output_log_2
```

and not like this:

```
some_command >output_log_1 >output_log_2
```

[zsh manual's Multios section](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Redirection.html#Multios) explains the reason with an example.

> There is a problem when an output multio is attached to an external program. A simple example shows this:
>
> ```
> cat file >file1 >file2
> cat file1 file2
> ```
>
> Here, it is possible that the second ‘`cat`’ will not display the full contents of `file1` and `file2` (i.e. the original contents of `file` repeated twice).
>
> The reason for this is that the multios are spawned after the cat process is forked from the parent shell, so the parent shell does not wait for the multios to finish writing data. This means the command as shown can exit before `file1` and `file2` are completely written. As a workaround, it is possible to run the `cat` process as part of a job in the current shell:
>
> ```
> { cat file } >file1 >file2
> ```
>
> Here, the `{...}` job will pause to wait for both files to be written.

So the safe way would be to always enclose the command in braces if one wants to be sure that the copy finishes before they can consume it in following commands.

Answer (score 4):

As @jofel mentioned in a comment under the answer, this can be done natively in `zsh`:

```
echo foobar >file1 >file2 >file3
```

or, with brace expansion:

```
echo foobar >file{1..3}
```

Internally this works very similarly to the `tee` answers provided above. The shell connects the command's stdout to a process that pipes to multiple files; therefore, there isn't any compelling technical advantage to doing it this way (but it *does* look real good). See [the `zsh` manual](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Redirection.html) for more.

Answer (score 3):

Unable to comment, however, another way to express

```
echo "foobarbaz" | tee file1 file2 file3 file4 file5 file6 file7 file8 > /dev/null
```

Could be simplified to this, when dealing with many files.

```
echo "foobarbaz" | tee file{1..8} > /dev/null
```

Comment: How is this really different from the other answers already given?  Especially since few people likely want literal `file1` through `file8` as their names and those are likely just example placeholders for the names of the files

Comment: Likely or not, this is exactly the solution I needed, and thought it could help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

This is the millenial way using JSON, and splitting on newlines. It requires that the producer process in the pipeline writes JSON to stdout and then that gets parsed and multiplexed.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash


function fan_out_to_multiple_files() {(

    set -eo pipefail;
    local last_tidbit=''

    local first='true'
    local last_line=''

    while read line; do

        for i in $(echo "$line" | tr ';' '\n'); do

            last_line="${i}"

            if [[ "$first" == 'true' ]]; then
               first='false';
               i="${last_tidbit}${i}"
               last_tidbit='';
            fi

            echo "i is '$i'"
           ((
             file_path="$(echo "$i" | jq -r '.file_path')"

             if [[ -n "$file_path" ]]; then
                  echo "$i" > "$file_path"
              fi

           ) || { echo; }; ) &> /dev/null &

        done;

        # assign
        last_tidbit="$last_line"
        first='false';

      done;

      wait;
)}
```

you run it like this:

```
echo -e '{"file_path":"bar123.json"}\n{"file_path":"foo123.json"}' | fan_out_to_multiple_files
```

this will yield two files on your fs, named foo123.json and bar123.json.

note I write a lot of my bash functions like this:

```
function has_embedded_subshell {(
   set -eo pipefail; ## now I can set flags without ever effecting current shell
)}
```